# Using same connection to update is working on one server, not on the other

Tags: c#, sql, connection-string

I have windows service that's select some records. And it works like this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CMS.SettingsProvider.SqlHelperClass.ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT...", conn);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            <snip>
            build item IDs to update
        }
        UpdateRecords(conn, itemIDs);
    }
}
```

EDIT

Update function:

```
private void UpdateRecords(SqlConnection Connection, List<int> ItemIDs)
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update table...", Connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

I installed it as windows service in QA server and it updated records. In production server it's not updating records. Log indicates update procedure is not even called. What could be the reason?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `UpdateRecords`? Is it executing SQL?

Comment: may I edit your code and have you try something and tell us what the exception message is..? also if UdateRecords(conn, itemIDs) is a method please show the code for that method

Comment: Build Item IDs to update also from your Reader make sure that you are assigning a variable to what ever fields you want to be in the UpdateRecords.. is itemIDs a List<T> or a String..? if it's a string then you need to put UpdateRecords(Conn, itemIDs) inside the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preventive Action**

```
 1. SQL Server Profiler
 2. Code debugging using production Database credentials
```

---

**Sample Reference**

[**SQL SERVER – Introduction to SQL Server 2008 Profiler**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/03/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-profiler-2/)

---

**Corrective Actions/Code Corrections**

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnection string")) 
{
    con.Open();
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    { 
        string expression = "Parameter value";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "Your Stored Procedure";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Your Parameter Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = expression;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
        {
            if (dr.Read()) 
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Inbuilt SQL SERVER Profiler ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can't run profiler on production though. It has something to do with MultipleActiveResultSets=True? I tried and that didn't work either

Comment: ok. if you have production server credentials. you can debug the code by accesing the database using application at ur end?

Comment: When I run it from my end, same connection string, it works.
When I run it on QA server, same connection string, it works. 
When I run it on this production server, reading data, i.e. while loop works. Logging to log table works. Update doesn't

Comment: please make sure that the connection string while being used at production contains those username and password credentials which are authorized to add/edit records in database...

Comment: They are. It is updating the log table, which is in the same DB